# Problem with JBoss dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven-2, jboss, dependencies

I have code dependant on some JBoss provided libraries. I have added to my POM following dependency:

```
...
<repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
</repository>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I receive following error

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.jboss.aspects:jboss-transaction-aspects

Reason: Failed to build model from file 'C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\jboss\
aspects\jboss-transaction-aspects\1.0.0.GA\jboss-transaction-aspects-1.0.0.GA.po
m'.
Error: 'no more data available - expected end tags </dependency></dependencies><
/project> to close start tag <dependency> from line 48 and start tag <dependenci
es> from line 45 and start tag <project> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG
seen ...<groupId>org.jboss</groupId>\n    ... @50:5' for project org.jboss.aspec
ts:jboss-transaction-aspects
```

I couldn't "google" it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems either your dependencies tags are not matching, or you don't have them.